# Primefaces Radio Button Not Selectable When Rendered Using AJAX listener

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using custom layout of `p:selectOneRadio` with a datatable of `Questions`. Initially the `Resolved` column has a `p:radioButton` that is not rendered.  When a value of 3 is entered in the `p:inputNumber` box for that question, the listener sets that question as `resolvable` and the view successfully renders a radio button in the resolve column for that question. However the radio button is not selectable and I cannot figure out why it isn't selectable.

I need to have the radio render on an AJAX test event and be selectable. I've also tried updating using the panel id.  No luck.

Primefaces V11.

Here is a minimal code to demonstrate

```
<h:form id="form">
        <p:selectOneRadio id="yesNoNA" value="#{qAndA.toggleValue}" layout="custom">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="YES" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="NO" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="NA" itemValue="NA" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Resolved" itemValue="RESOLVED" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>

    <p:dataTable sshowGridlines="true" value="#{bean.questions}" var="qAndA" tableStyle="width:auto;">
        <p:column headerText="Attribute" width="40">
            <h:outputText value="#{qAndA.stem}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Yes" width="50">
            <p:radioButton id="yes" for="form:yesNoNA" itemIndex="0" rendered="#{empty qAndA.toggleValue}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="No" width="50">
            <p:radioButton id="no" for="form:yesNoNA" itemIndex="1" rendered="#{empty qAndA.toggleValue}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="N/A" width="50">
            <p:radioButton id="na" for="form:yesNoNA" itemIndex="2" rendered="#{empty qAndA.toggleValue}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Hours" width="50">
            <p:inputNumber inputStyle="width: 40px;" value="#{qAndA.hours}">
                <p:ajax listener="#{bean.toggleResolve()}" update="@(.jjj)" />
            </p:inputNumber>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Resolved" width="50">
            <h:panelGroup id="pGrpRes" styleClass="jjj">
                <p:radioButton id="resolved" for="form:yesNoNA" itemIndex="3" rendered="#{qAndA.resolvable}" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

---

```
@Named(value = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class RadioBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
 
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Question q1 = new Question();
        q1.setStem("Question 1");

        Question q2 = new Question();
        q2.setStem("Question 2");

        Question q3 = new Question();
        q3.setStem("Question 3");

        questions.add(q1);
        questions.add(q2);
        questions.add(q3);

    }

    public void toggleResolve() {

        for (Question q : questions) {
            q.setResolvable(false);
            if (q.getHours() == 3) {
                q.setResolvable(true);
            } 
        }

    }


    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Question {

    private String stem;
    private String toggleValue;
    private int hours = 0;
    private boolean resolvable = false;

}
```

Comment: There have been some issues with the custom radio button. Can you please try with PrimeFaces 12 (SNAPSHOT) (please read the migration guide and custom layout docs).

Comment: How do I get 12?  I only see 11 as the latest at Maven Central and PF.com

Comment: You'll need to clone https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces.git and build it. I think your issue might be related to / fixed by https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/8378